# Motivation of the sheaf associated to $M$ on Proj $S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am wondering why the $\tilde{M}$ is defined like that.

To be more precise, when $S=\mathbb{C}[x_0,...,x_n]$. $X:=$Proj $S=\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^n$. $\tilde{M}$ is similar to the sheaf defined on the projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$. In particular, $\mathcal{O}_X(k)$ is like the line bundle on $\mathbb{C}P^n$. My question is: Is there a motivation that $\mathcal{O}_X(k)$ is defined to be the set of functions $s$ from $U$ to $\coprod_{p\in U}S(k)_{(p)}$? How is this definition related to the definition of line bundle or sheaf on $\mathbb{C}P^n$? What's the motivation of using the localization here for $S(k)_{(p)}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of sheafification? Although Hartshorne makes no mention of this, his definition is really the sheafification of a presheaf that is quite intuitive, as described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/80560/). (You are talking about the definition in Hartshorne, right?) As an aside, I find the definition using only basic open sets much more intuitive, as given in EGA or Ravi Vakil's book.

Comment: That is almost certainly not the usual definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(k)$. Additionally it is almost certainly incomplete, since there should be restrictions on the functions, for one, that they should be sections of the canonical projection. Can you provide a bit more context? I would expect the definition to be for $f\in S$ of positive degree, $\tilde{M}$ on the distinguished affine open $D_+(f)$ is just the module corresponding to $(M_f)_0$. Once one has a sheaf, one can then flatten it out into the espace etale and get more or less the definition you've given plus the proper conditions.